# PHP. Get information about facebook user

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

i have made a web server in php, it receives the facebook userAccessToken by my webApp and it checks if it's valid, i want get the basic info about that user but i don't find a way to do this. Someone can help me?

Comment: ty it with simple js api

Comment: i need do it with php server side. i already do it with Js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
      require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

      $config = array(
        'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
        'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
      );

      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
    ?>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>



    <?php
        if($user_id) {

          // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
          // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
          try {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
            echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];

          } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
            // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
            // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
            // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
            // just ask the user to login again here.
            $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
            echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
            error_log($e->getType());
            error_log($e->getMessage());
          }   
        } else {

          // No user, print a link for the user to login
          $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
          echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

        }

      ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Once you are logged in use this command to retrieve user data array:

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

Or you can use this to get user by ID (other user)

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('userID','GET');
```

Everything you need you can find here:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/
```

Comment: i don't understand this code. the line $user_id = $facebook->getUser() which user it returns? where you do the login o give to $facebook the userToken?

Comment: $facebook->api('/me','GET'); this gets the user you have, your personal facebook user.

Comment: You have already created an app? that is needed in order for your script to login to facebook

Comment: i have already created an app, i have don login with JS. i don't still understand this, it suppone that some users are already logged in but how? i have logged users with JS not with PHP.

Comment: the tags in your post are PHP, oauth... etc
If you want js only use this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Comment: i don't want use JS. i already have a userToken and want get information about that user, all of this in php

Comment: well the code you have there in PHP is very simple. What exactly don't you understand? 

$user_id = $facebook->getUser(); this is used to check if the auth is ok, then you get the full data by calling: $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

Comment: where is the pice of code where you give to facebook the userToken? this is what i don't understand. Because if i try this code with my app_id and secrete_code $user is always 0

Comment: Get access token after the app is registered: 
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();